# I do not see the css applied to the div tags. Why is that?

Tags: html, css

Through the following snippet, I try to print the text `FileName` and `NodeThatShared` with some decoration. But it prints as if I didn't use the `css` *(in a simple manner)*. What could be the reason for this ?

```
HTML :

<div id="FileName">
    FileName
</div>

<div id="NodeThatShared">
    NodeThatShared
</div>
```

---

```
CSS:

root { 
  display: block;
}

FileName {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold;
}

NodeThatShared {
  font-size:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
#FileName

#NodeThatShared
```

`.` indicates an HTML class
`#` indicates an HTML ID

So `<div id="test">` is `#test` and `<div class="test">` is `.test`.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the # symbol before the ID name in your CSS file.

If you decide to use classes, put a . before the class name.

Your CSS should look like this:

```
#FileName {
    font-size:10px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#NodeThatShared {
    font-size:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not selecting the elements properly, here is the proper way:

```
#FileName {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#NodeThatShared {
  font-size:9px;
}
```

CSS selectors for classes are denoted by a '.' and a '#' for ids.

Here is an example of both:

```
<div class="my_class">This div is styled by a class selector</div>
<div id="my_id">This div is styled by an id selector</div>

.my_class { backgroud:orange; }
#my_id    { background:red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS IDs need to be prefixed with a pound sign `#`

```
#FileName {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#NodeThatShared {
  font-size:9px;
}
```

CSS classes need to be prefixed with a period `.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the selector's type to the front. Like:

```
#FileName {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold;
 }

#NodeThatShared {
  font-size:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `#` sign that indicates an ID.

<sup>(I hate it when it doesn't allow me to post (requires at least 30 characters) when only one symbol answers the question)</sup>

```css
#FileName {
  font-size:10px;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#NodeThatShared {
  font-size:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference an `id` in css you use:

```
#{id name}
```

In your case it would be:

```
#FileName

#NodeThatShared
```

If you refernce a `class` in css it would be:

```
.{class name}
```

Such as:

```
.class1

.class2
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, an ID needs to reference something in your style sheet that has a "#" sign in front of it.  For example:

```
 #FileName {
font-size:10px;
 text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}

 #NodeThatShared {
font-size:9px;
}
```

Remember that this only applies to ID's.  To use classes it would look like this:

```
 .FileName {
font-size:10px;
 text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}

 .NodeThatShared {
font-size:9px;
}
```

Classes can be used more than once.